# Can anything good happen in a drunken stupor?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I'm wandering around in a drunken stupor. So far, nothing but bad things have happened. Can anything good happen, or should I just leave it until tomorrow?

Comment: Have they finally completed the "life-simulating" video game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only on St. Sneaky Pete's day can anything good happen while you're falling down drunk. Just sleep it off, man.